# Periodic manual ANALYZE for PostgreSQL tables

Tags: postgresql

I am working with a PostgreSQL (currently version 13 and 14) schema deployed on hundreds of PG instances (databases). Each instance holds different data and is used slightly differently.

From time to time, I notice that one of the instances shows a severe degradation in the performance of a specific query. In most cases, running `ANALYZE;` on the table solves the performance degradation.

There are a wide range of examples of this happening; here's one:

> The last time it was due to a migration that added an index, a simple query that should have used this index started using a different index. That query had some JOINs. Without them, the query used the new index. After running ANALYZE; the query started using the correct index with the JOINs.

One thing that I considered to battle this is to have a worker that would periodically `ANALYZE;` all tables in the database. Since `ANALYZE` runs quite quickly and doesn't have risks related to it, that seems like a good idea.

I can't help but wonder though: is it a good practice in cases similar to mine? Is there some configuration or fine tuning that is preferred to running `ANALYZE;` periodically and achieves the same effect?

Comment: Was the new index an expression index or a regular column index?

Comment: You say query `had` some joins, that means query has changed?

Comment: Just tune autovacuum and autoanalyze, that should do the trick.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN I modified the query in order to debug why the performance (effectively plan) change.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe wouldn't the process of tuning automvacuum and autoanalyze be very time consuming, considering I need to manage hundreds of databases and each one, despite of having identical schema, is often used differently?

Comment: @jjanes it was a regular column index

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with the suggestion. My follow up question is whether this in general would need to be done for each of the databases, or given the same schema there would be a common configuration for autovacuum and autoanalyze? Regarding running analyze periodically, that's actually trivial in terms of effort, but it's not clear to me what would be the downsides of it.

Comment: Read [Autovacuum Daemon](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM). This of course assumes  you mean databases in a given Postgres cluster.  This; *...deployed on hundreds of PG instances (databases).* is somewhat ambiguous.  An `instance` is usually taken to mean a Postgres cluster and a `database` the result of `CREATE DATABASE` in that cluster. You might want to update the question with a clearer definition of your setup.

Comment: It is hard to see how writing your own autovac knockoff is likely to be less time consuming than identifying the problem with the existing one and fixing it.

Comment: You only have to tune it once (and monitor it). It' may be a lot of work initially, but then no more work until you retire.

Comment: Sorry @adrian-klaver, I have hundreds of database clusters. Some of them are running multiple databases, but most are running only one database. So yes, hundreds of database clusters... In any case I will read the documentation you suggest, but doing manual tuning on each cluster might not be feasible. Sorry if my original question wasn't clear enough.